# What is the meaning of <<<

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection

I found this code in a script at the end of a while loop

```
done <<< $filenames
```

In the script, `$filenames` is a variable used to collect a list of files from a database.  The loop processes each sub-string in the `$filenames` list.
The question I have is what does the `<<<` do?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: Yes I read the man page and searched.  Perhaps my search was too specific.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings

Comment: All you have to do is open that documentation and search with the browser for `<<<`

Answer (score 1):

`<<<` is essentially a one-line heredoc (a "here string").

```
$ cat <<< blah
blah
```

which is equivalent to a heredoc like:

```
$ cat <<EOF
> blah
> EOF
blah
```

Comment: Or equiv to `echo blah | cat`

Comment: And the one-line heredoc provides then input to subsequent READ loop.

Comment: @Barmar Similar, but not entirely equivalent. A pipe runs each side in  a sub-process, meaning variable changes would be lost. `<<<` works within the current shell process.

Answer (score 0):

`<<<` operator is used to fed input to the corresponding command on it's left side.